# Ampersand url encoding and query string parameter issue

Tags: asp.net, querystringparameter, navigateurl

I have had an aspx project dumped on my lap and I have the following issue.

They are calling a function within the NavigateUrl of a hyperlink and the '&'s are being encoded

```
href="/products/automotive-glass/?position=whatever&amp;brand=whatever"
```

but when clicked this encoding is shown in the address bar. Then when I try and get the value of the query string parameter

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="brand" QueryStringField="brand" />
```

to pass to a function it does not find it because the parameters name is actually amp;brand

Is there a way to either not include the encoding in the address bar or a way of getting the parameter value with the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in static class utility methods `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to encode and decode the Url.  You'll need a reference to `System.Web` in order to use them.  Here is a link to some documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx